# HTML inside XML CDATA being converted with &lt; and &gt; brackets

Tags: xml, xslt, asp-classic, cdata

I have some sample XML:

```
<sample><![CDATA[Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3<br />]]></sample>
```

I'm using ASP to output this XML using a stylesheet like so:

```
Set xmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xmlHttp.open "GET", URLxml, false
xmlHttp.send()

Set xslHttp = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xslHttp.open "GET", xXsl, false
xslHttp.send()   

Set xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("MICROSOFT.XMLDOM")
Set xslDoc = Server.CreateObject("MICROSOFT.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.async = false
xslDoc.async = false
xmlDoc.Load xmlHttp.responseXML
xslDoc.Load xslHttp.responseXML

Response.Write xmlDoc.transformNode(xslDoc)
```

However, once this is getting written, the HTML output is showing up as:

```
Line 1&lt;br /&gt;Line 2&lt;br /&gt;Line 3
```

I can see that ASP is converting the brackets in the code, but I'm not sure why.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Good question, +1. In addition to the good explanation by @Alejandro, see my answer describing the best possible solution to the problem.

Comment: +1 question is clear and seeks a definitive answer - that noted, posting the XSL document would help.

Comment: The portion of the XSL that is outputting this data is a simple <xsl:value-of select="sample"/>.

Answer (score 3):

> I have some sample XML:
>
> ```
> <sample><![CDATA[Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3<br />]]></sample>
> ```

This is a `sample` element with a **text node** child.

Suppose you apply an identity transform. Then the result will be:

```
<sample>Line 1&lt;br /&gt;Line 2&lt;br /&gt;Line 3&lt;br /&gt;</sample>
```

Why? Because text nodes and attribute values have the special character `&`, `<` and `>` escape as character entities.

**EDIT**: Of course, you could use DOE... But, besides that it's an **optional feature**, the result will be a text node no matter what (without the encode character entities). You will need other parser fase (this may be useful when output and encode HTML fragment to a (X)HTML document like in feeds, with the risk of malformed output...).

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="sample">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<p>Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3<br /></p>
```

Render as (actual markup):

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

Comment: But being within a CDATA statement shouldn't that be outputting as written?  Isn't that the purpose of a CDATA, to basically ignore any special characters within it?

Comment: The purpose of a CDATA statement is to offer another way to serialize data. Code blocks `<sample><![CDATA[<br />]]></sample>` and `<sample>&lt;br /&gt;</sample>` are *semantically* the same. In both cases there is a sample element which contents is `<br />` as a text string, not as an element. HTML output is HTML serialization of your data and even in HTML you need to escape `<` characters.

Comment: @Steve K.: CDATA section say: *"Do not parse this, treat it like text"*

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Alejandro's explanation, here is the best possible solution:

**Never put markup in a text (CDATA) node**.

Instead of:

```
<sample><![CDATA[Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3<br />]]></sample>
```

always create:

```
<sample>Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3<br /></sample>
```

**Remember**: Putting markup inside of CDATA is losing it.

Answer (score 1):

Think it's the XSL transformation that's causing you problems. You should be able to edit your .xsl document to correct this as such:

```
<xsl:template match=".">
  <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  <!-- ... other XSL business here ... -->
</xsl:template>
```

I'm stealing from [this page about disable output escaping](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N2215.html).

For the record I hate XML/XSL - a solution in search of a problem. Generally speaking if you need to deal with markup I've found XML/XSL only introduces problems because frequently you want to deal with markup fragments, which are often not valid XML, so you wrap CDATA around it and then hilarity ensues as you're experiencing.

**Update**

OK, so the above didn't work. Of course didn't know what XSL looked like until comment on question was added. The following does work (idea from [this forum thread](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=4401)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match=".">
        <xsl:value-of select="sample"  />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Key is the `<xsl:output method="text" />`.

Comment: @orangepics: Yeah! Consistently Treating unparsed data as parseable data is not part of your problem...

Comment: Trying to add the disable-out-escaping parameter didn't succeed.  It seems like ASP is the culprit that is actually changing it on the output.  I've also found that it's changing &'s to &amp;'s ...

Comment: @orangepips: `.` it's not a valid pattern... Also, you're output method is `text`; that adds the need to built yourself the element markup...

Comment: @Alejandro: I think the questioner's markup is already built, but maybe this reflects my imperfect XSL knowledge. When I apply that XSL to this XML: <sample><![CDATA[Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3<br />]]></sample> I receive the output Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3<br />.

Comment: @orangepips: First, you can't run you transformation: `.` is an invalid pattern. Second, I tend to think that the OP probably wants to output more that just the encode (X)HTML, i.e. a wrapping `p`. How would you do that preserving your `text` output method?

Comment: @Alejandro: I'm running the transformation successfully in Java using the aforementioned XML and XSL. Don't have ASP system stood up anywhere. Your point about wrapping with other items is valid, I think to answer the question fully then need the XML and XSL data.